# How to change states at the end of an animation transition? - Angular 2

Tags: angular, animation, typescript, state

Hi I'm trying to get my angular 2 app to do router transitions as shown from this tutorial.

[Router Transition Tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-animate-router-transitions-6de179e00204#.7j6rhlfmz)

[Demo Link](https://embed.plnkr.co/PcRpcGK2duGw0HdaGaF5/?show=preview)

I'm really new to animations and am having problems with the state leaving the component styles at **position: fixed** allowing no scrolling. I would like to know how I can change the state to a user defined state at the end of the **:entry** transition.

```
function slideToRight() {
  return trigger('routerTransition', [
    state('void', style({position:'fixed', width:'100%'}) ),
    state('*', style({position:'fixed', width:'100%'}) ),
    state('visible', style({position:'static', width:'initial'}) ),
    transition(':enter => visible', [ //<-- my attempt at switching the state
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'})),
    ]),
    transition('visible => :leave', [ //<-- my attempt at switching the state
      style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
    ])
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Finally I understand what was wrong with fixed... hehe =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the `style` inside the transition instead.

Example with `slideToLeft` function:

```
function slideToLeft() {
  return trigger('routerTransition', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', position:'fixed', width:'100%'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(0%)', position:'fixed', width:'100%'}),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))
    ])
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It fixed it! : )